# No scrollbar shown when element is bigger than its flexbox container

Tags: css, layout, contenteditable, flexbox

Flexbox can be used to vertically align elements. But when a vertically-aligned element later grows, it can escape the bounds of its flexbox container. This happens even when `overflow:auto` is used on the element.

Here's a demo with some expected and actual results.

**Using the demo:**

1. [Open the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/openjck/j5o96vgn/)
2. Enter lots of text in the gray box

**Expected result:**

The paragraph becomes taller as text is entered. When the paragraph is as tall as its flexbox container, it stops growing and a vertical scrollbar is shown.

**Actual result:**

The paragraph becomes taller as text is entered, but never stops growing. It ultimately escapes the bounds of its flexbox container. A scrollbar is never shown.

**Other notes:**

It's tempting to put `overflow:auto` on the container instead, but that doesn't work as expected. Try it out. Enter lots of text and then scroll up. Notice that the top padding is gone and lines of text are missing.

Comment: I've just tried to populate the gray area with long text and vertical scroll bar appeared: so, what's exactly a problem in your case? Thanks and regards,

Comment: Strange, I'm not seeing that. I'm seeing [the gray area overflow its container](http://i.imgur.com/uEnGk41.png). What browser/version are you on?

Comment: I am using FF V34.0, I guess the latest one.

Comment: Hm, I'm also using 34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Add "max-height: 100%" on the `<p>` element to keep it from growing indefinitely.
2. If you want to keep your `padding` on the `<p>`, you *also* need to set `box-sizing: border-box` to get its padding included in that `max-height`.

(Technically `box-sizing:padding-box` is what you want, but Chrome doesn't support that; so, `border-box` will do, because it's the same as the padding-box since there's no border.)

[Here's your JS Fiddle with this fix](http://jsfiddle.net/j5o96vgn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

In your `css` you need to give `height`

```
p {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    outline: none;
    height: 60px;

}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5o96vgn/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The goal is for the paragraph to be vertically centered at first, and then grow to be (at most) as tall as the container, so a fixed height wouldn't be enough.